# Form grid filters

Tags: forms, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I want store the filters entered on the grid, is it possible to store the filters entered on filter pane of the grid.

I want to use those filters entered in my class, please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can retrieve the filters by getting the form's `queryRun`'s `query` and packing that into a container to be stored/passed/unpacked.

The form has a `query`, that is passed to `QueryRun`, then the users puts filters/dynamic joins/etc on that `query` that belongs to the `QueryRun`.  So you need the modified `query` to store what you want from it.

```
void clicked()
{
    Query   q = salestable_ds.queryRun().query();
    int     i;
    container c;


    for (i = 1; i <= q.queryFilterCount(); i++)
    {
        info(strFmt("%1: %2", q.queryFilter(i).field(), q.queryFilter(i).value()));
    }   

    // If we want to store these we can do
    c = q.pack();
}
```

See this post http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/t/63208.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No, form queries cannot be saved as code (but such functionality could be programmed).

A form query could be passed from the form to a class, using a `parmQueryRun` method or similar.

See:

- [How to Create Queries by using the AOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb314753.aspx)
- [How to Create Queries by Using X++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa638454.aspx)

Comment: In AX 12 you can save the form queries unless I misunderstood the question/answer.